# Checking if text exists in page source of url

Tags: javascript, html, xml, url

I'f searched a lot. Found information about how to check if certain string is present on current webpage. I spent a few hours to find out my question:
I'm using an XML file with clientdetails.

```
<Name>Name</Name>
<Url>home.example.com</Url>
```

I use:

```
window.XMLHttpRequest
```

to get the information. And

```
getElementsByTagName("Url")
```

to get the Url which belongs to the name of the client.

Now i need to check with javascript if there is a certain string present in the sourcecode of this external url for every client. So javascript maybe must open the sourcecode of the url in background and find for the text string?

As output I need an overview of every client which has this text string present in the clients url sourcecode in a div.

I want the script to perform this action every 30 minutes (set interval).

Can anybody tell me how to check the sourcecode of an external url (related to client in xml file) for a text string?

Thanks

---

Right now I'am using this, but it isn't working to check whether cross-domain url from xml file contains text string in source/page. Can anybody help?

```
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open     ("GET","http://www.example.nl/check/clients.xml",false);
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Table1");
i=0
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
// hasMyString = true, if the response contains a given string.
var hasMyString = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue).innerText.indexOf('action') !== -1;
  }
  alert("Action Found"); 
}

</script>
```

Comment: Does "external url" mean cross-domain?

Comment: yes, indeed cross-domain, actually it's in <svg> </svg>

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a substring exists in a string with `String#indexOf`, so it's just a matter of getting the XHR's response text and finding the string you need within.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( ... );
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    // hasMyString = true, if the response contains a given string.
    var hasMyString = xhr.innerText.indexOf( ... ) !== -1;
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry. Right now I use this, but it isn't working. What can I do more?